# Designing differerntial Sigal modulator

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, modulation

I would like your suggestion on my first design Differential signal modulator [simulation attached].

Before jumping into design let me highlight my objective.  I am differentiating a control signal of 1MHz and then modulating it with carrier frequency 15MHz(not limited to this specific value but for testing). The whole modulator needs to be integrated on a silicon substrate, in other words, the design should comply with IC design regulations i.e. occupy less space, power-efficient, and simple. The current design consumes 5.6mW power.

***So I would request suggestions who had experience in a related field, that***

**1-How can I further improve this design?**

**2-Is there other alternatives design that would be much better than this one?**

Your suggestions and comments will be highly appreciated. Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) *I am differentiating a control signal of 1MHz and then modulating it with carrier frequency 15MHz* I would call this on/off amplitude modulation (OOK modulation) where the carrier is 15 MHz and the modulation signal is 1 MHz. 2) Why use **two** oscillators? I would use only **one** and save some space (mainly resistor and capacitor). Then use a small logic circuit to feed the oscillator's output to V_diff1 or V_diff_2.

Comment: *I am differentiating a control signal* Not really, you're **inverting** the PWM I/P signal. In a differentiator I need to see a capacitor, I only see a CMOS inverter so you're inverting. Maybe you mean you're making a **differential** signal as you have the input signal and its inverse signal (at the output of the inverter).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks for your comments.
1- "Not really, you're inverting the PWM I/P signal. In a differentiator I need to see a capacitor, I only see a CMOS inverter"

     Actually message signal is a PWM control signal with varying pulse width. 
      For testing, I took PWM with constant pulse width. Moreover where I would need to 
      use a capacitor as you mention? 

In your first comment you point out that I can use one oscillator for modulation to save space then how can I modulate diff signal with one oscillator?